# shiny - actionButton #1 works exact same actionButton #2 doesnt

Tags: r, shiny

I am pretty new to shiny and I am trying to build a web application that downloads datasets from GEO or lets user upload his own. Be able to show the data to user in boxplot format and table format then let user decide whether data is to be normalized or log transformed. My issue is the actionButton in the later order in the code does not work. If I press the first actionButton and then press second actionButton both works oddly. But if I choose to press second actionButton directly it does nothing. Here is my code:

ui.R

```
   library(shiny)
library(som)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  #
  headerPanel("Dataset Selection"),
  # Sidebar with controls to select a dataset and specify the number
  # of observations to view
  sidebarPanel(

    actionButton("Gobutton", "Bring it up"),

    fluidRow()
  ),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Dataset", 
               fluidRow(
                 column(8, uiOutput("dataTable"),
                        tags$style(type='text/css', '#view {background-color: rgba(11,56,49,0.2); color: black; font-family:verdana;}') ))
      ),
      tabPanel("Boxplot",
               fluidRow(
                 column(8,plotOutput("preprocessData"),
                        tags$style(type='text/css', '#view {background-color: rgba(11,56,49,0.2); color: black; font-family:verdana;}'))),
               conditionalPanel(condition = "input.NormalizeButton <= 0",
                                actionButton("NormalizeButton","Normalize")),
               conditionalPanel(condition = "input.LogTransformButton <= 0",
                                actionButton("LogTransformButton", "Log2 Transform"))
      ))
  )
)
)
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  library(xtable)
  # You can access the value of the widget with input$num, e.g.
  GSEmRNA <- data.frame(from=c(100,200,150), to=c(1000,2000,150),last= c(50,50,250))

  normalizeSom <- function(GSEmRNA){
    colnamesSAVE <- colnames(GSEmRNA)
    GSEmRNA <- som::normalize(GSEmRNA)    # Normalize the dataset using som package of R
    colnames(GSEmRNA) <- colnamesSAVE
    boxplot(GSEmRNA)
    print(colnames(GSEmRNA))
    return(GSEmRNA)
  }

  todoLogTransformation <- function(GSEmRNA) {
    GSEmRNA <- log(GSEmRNA,2)
    boxplot(GSEmRNA)
    return(GSEmRNA)
  }

  output$dataTable <- renderUI({
    input$Gobutton
    if (input$Gobutton== 0) {return()}        
    else{
      GSEmRNAprinted <- print(xtable(head(GSEmRNA), align=rep("c", ncol(GSEmRNA)+1)), 
                              floating=FALSE, tabular.environment="array", comment=FALSE, print.results=FALSE)
      html <- paste0("$$", GSEmRNAprinted, "$$")
      list(
        withMathJax(HTML(html)))}
  })
  output$preprocessData <- renderPlot({
    if (input$Gobutton== 0) {return()}        
    else{
    boxplot(GSEmRNA)
    input$LogTransformButton
    if(input$LogTransformButton ==0){return()}
    else if(input$LogTransformButton != 0 ){
      GSEmRNA <<- todoLogTransformation(GSEmRNA)
    }
    input$NormalizeButton
    if(input$NormalizeButton ==0){return()}
    else if(input$NormalizeButton != 0){
      GSEmRNA <<- normalizeSom(GSEmRNA)
    }}
  })

})
```

Also lastly, I want the table I described in the output$dataTable <- renderUI to be renewed each time user presses normalize or log transform. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have been working on this for quite some time

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you can provide a very simplified version of your program. Try to isolate the problem using the minimum libraries, maybe just the shiny in this case.

Comment: I modified the code to be more minimalistic. Thanks for your input

Comment: Try to create example with simple `data.frame` to show what your want(to allow people without `GEOquery` trying to fix it). Also you may be have to use `reactiveValues` for data( and not use `<<-` ). see `observeEvent` which allow you change your `reactiveValues`

Comment: Editing done. Does not need GEOquery atm to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

1) Delete from your code all what not influence( css and panel-- for simplicity)

2) All function declare outside server -- think it will work better

3) use reactive values for data

UI

```
library(shiny)
library(som)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Dataset Selection"),

  sidebarPanel(
     actionButton("Gobutton", "Bring it up")
  ),
  mainPanel(
   wellPanel(
               fluidRow(
                 column(8, uiOutput("dataTable")
                        ))
   ),
   wellPanel(
               fluidRow(
                 column(8,plotOutput("preprocessData")
                       )),
               conditionalPanel(condition = "input.NormalizeButton <= 0",
                                actionButton("NormalizeButton","Normalize")),
               conditionalPanel(condition = "input.LogTransformButton <= 0",
                                actionButton("LogTransformButton", "Log2 Transform"))

  )
  )
)
)
```

server

```
normalizeSom <- function(GSEmRNA){
  colnamesSAVE <- colnames(GSEmRNA)
  GSEmRNA <- som::normalize(GSEmRNA)    # Normalize the dataset using som package of R
  colnames(GSEmRNA) <- colnamesSAVE
    return(GSEmRNA)
}

todoLogTransformation <- function(GSEmRNA) {
  GSEmRNA <- log(GSEmRNA,2)
   return(GSEmRNA)
}

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  library(xtable)
  # You can access the value of the widget with input$num, e.g.
  GSEmRNA <- data.frame(from=c(100,200,150), to=c(1000,2000,150),last= c(50,50,250))
  data_for_use=reactiveValues(d=GSEmRNA)


  output$dataTable <- renderUI({
    if (input$Gobutton== 0) {return()}        
    else{
      GSEmRNAprinted <- print(xtable(head(data_for_use$d), align=rep("c", ncol(data_for_use$d)+1)), 
                              floating=FALSE, tabular.environment="array", comment=FALSE, print.results=FALSE)
      html <- paste0("$$", GSEmRNAprinted, "$$")
      list(
        withMathJax(HTML(html)))}
  })

  output$preprocessData <- renderPlot({

    if (input$Gobutton== 0) {return()
    }else{
      boxplot(data_for_use$d)

      }
  })

  observeEvent(input$NormalizeButton,{
    data_for_use$d=normalizeSom(data_for_use$d)
  })
  observeEvent(input$LogTransformButton,{
    data_for_use$d=todoLogTransformation(data_for_use$d)
  })
})
```

Comment: Had to put all the functions back inside because couldnt make it work this way but in the end this answer made me reach to a properly working shiny web application. Thanks a lot for this, it is really appreciated